# Convert int to int array

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion

And now I have another issue.
I need to make a CNF formula and use a map of integres of 3d array.
now I try to use this task, with a difference of inset an 3d array, and not 2d.

I did it with columns(where the are 2 stars(**)) and it works.

With the blocks (where you can see ********* stars), the eclipse says that "cannot convert fron int to []int"

why does it write that?
in the "columns it does not".

I hope I was clear.

```
public static void encode(int sqrtN, int[][] hints, int[][][] map) {
    int[] vars = new int [sqrtN*sqrtN]; 
    int nVars = sqrtN*sqrtN*sqrtN*sqrtN*sqrtN*sqrtN;


**  //each cell in the columns gets a different value.**
    for(int i=0; i<sqrtN*sqrtN; i=i+1){
        for(int j=0; j<sqrtN*sqrtN; j=j+1) {
            for(int k=0; k<sqrtN*sqrtN; k=k+1) 
                vars[k] = columns(map)[i][k][j];

            SATSolver.addClauses(exactlyOne(vars));
        }   
    }

    *****//each cell in the blocks gets a different value.******
    for(int i=0; i<sqrtN*sqrtN; i=i+1){
        for(int j=0; j<sqrtN*sqrtN; j=j+1) {
            for(int k=0; k<sqrtN*sqrtN; k=k+1) 
                vars[k] = blocks(map,sqrtN)[i][k][j];

            SATSolver.addClauses(exactlyOne(vars));
        }   
    }
    //hints.
    int [] hintsSATS = new int[1];
    for (int i = 0; i < hints.length; i = i + 1) {
        hintsSATS[0] = varName(hints[i][0],hints[i][1],hints[i][2]-1,sqrtN*sqrtN);
        SATSolver.addClause(hintsSATS);
    }

}

 //A function to trunsfer to columns.
public static int[][][] columns (int[][][] matrix) {
    int[][][] columns = new int[matrix.length][matrix.length][matrix.length];
    for(int j=0; j<matrix.length; j= j+1){
        for(int i=0; i<matrix.length; i= i+1){
            columns[j][i] = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    return columns;
}

  ************  //A function to trunsfer to blocks.**********
public static int[][][] blocks (int[][][] matrix, int sqrtN) {  
    int[][][] blocks = matrix;
    for (int i = 0; i<matrix.length; i= i+1) {
        for (int j = 0; j<matrix.length; j= j+1) {
            blocks[i][j] = j%sqrtN+ i%sqrtN*sqrtN + 1;
        }
    }
    return blocks;
}




//The name of the variable.
public static int varName(int i, int j, int k, int n) {
    int varName = n*n*i+n*j+k+1;
    return varName;
}
    //functions for the CNF. Excactly one.

public static int[][] atLeastOne(int[] vars) {
    int [][] atLeastOne = new int [1][vars.length];
    atLeastOne[0] = vars;
    return atLeastOne;  
}

public static int[][] atMostOne(int[] vars) {
    int [][]atMostOne = new int[AmountOfArrays(vars.length)][2];
    int k = 0;
    for(int i= 0;i<vars.length;i= i+1){
        for( int j=i+1;j<vars.length;j= j+1){
            atMostOne[k][0] = -vars[i];
            atMostOne[k][1] = -vars[j];
            k=k+1;          
        }
    }
    return atMostOne;
}

public static int AmountOfArrays(int n){
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i= 0;i<n-1;i= i+1){
        for( int j=i+1;j<n;j= j+1){
            counter= counter+1;         
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

public static int[][] exactlyOne(int[] vars) {
    int [][] exactlyOne = new int [AmountOfArrays(vars.length)+1][vars.length];
    int [][]atLeastOne = new int [1][vars.length];
    atLeastOne = atLeastOne(vars);
    exactlyOne[0] = atLeastOne[0];
    for(int i=1; i<exactlyOne.length; i= i+1){
        int [][]atMostOne = atMostOne(vars);
        exactlyOne[i] = atMostOne[i-1];
    }
    return exactlyOne;
}
```

Comment: Can you narrow down the code a little?

Comment: blocks is of type int[][][]. Then blocks[i][j] is simply of type int[]. Probably you need a third loop for the third dimension.

Comment: [mcve] is the key for your question...

Answer (score 1):

problem is here `blocks[i][j] = j%sqrtN+ i%sqrtN*sqrtN + 1;`
the `blocks[i][j]` needs an array but `j%sqrtN+ i%sqrtN*sqrtN + 1;` return an int.

Answer (score 0):

In the method `public static int[][][] blocks (int[][][] matrix, int sqrtN)`, you are not using the multi array `matrix` correctly.

```
matrix -> int[][][]
matrix[i] -> int[][]
matrix[i][j] -> int[]
matric[i][j][k] -> int
```

So you need to add a loop to iterate on one more array dimension to be able to set an `int` value in the cells.

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; ++j) {
        for (int k = 0; k < matrix[i][j].length; ++k) {
            blocks[i][j][k] = ????
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I used `matrix[i].length`, if you array dimension are not all the same size, this is safer.

Comment: So why it is work in the "public static int[][][] columns (int[][][] matrix)" function? it is exactly the same idea. If I am not wrong...